# ng-repeat with ng-click inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to create a simple autocomplete tag directive. But the `ng-click` on the dropdown menu `<li>` won't fire. I am sure this is some sort of scope issue, but I don't get why. Can someone please show me how to get this ng-click to fire? thanks!

here is the template:

```
<article ng-click="focus()">

  <div class="tags-container">

    <div ng-repeat="selectedTag in selectedTags" ng-click='removeTag($index)' class="tag">
      <span class="tagName">{{selectedTag}}</span>
    </div>

    <input type="text" ng-focus='activate()' ng-blur='listActive = false' id="searchInput" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" class="tags" ng-model="searchText" />

  </div>

  <ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions-list" ng-class="{active : listActive}">
    <li ng-repeat="tag in tagList | filter:searchText" class="tags" ng-click="addToSelectedTags($index)" ng-mouseover="$parent.index=$index" ng-class="{active : index===$index}">
      <strong>{{tag}}</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>

</article>
```

Here is the directive

```
angular
  .module('directives')

.directive('tagComplete', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      selectedTags: '=',
      tagList: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'public/partials/tagAutocomplete.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.index = -1;
      scope.listActive = false;
      scope.test = 'false';

      scope.removeTag = function(index) {
        scope.selectedTags.splice(index, 1);
      };

      scope.addToSelectedTags = function(index) {
        var isSelected = _.includes(scope.selectedTags, scope.tagList[index]);

        if (!isSelected) {
          scope.selectedTags.push(scope.tagList[index]);
          scope.searchText = '';
          scope.index = -1;
        }
      };

      scope.focus = function() {
        console.log(scope.test);
        $(elem).find('#searchInput').focus();
      };

      scope.activate = function() {
        if (scope.tagList.length > 0) {
          scope.listActive = true;
        }
      };

      scope.checkKeyDown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 40) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (scope.index + 1 !== scope.tagList.length) {
            scope.index++;
          }
        } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (scope.index - 1 !== -1) {
            scope.index--;
          }
        } else if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          scope.addToSelectedTags(scope.index);
        } else {
          scope.index = -1;
        }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the directive in the html

```
<tag-complete tag-list="vm.suggestions" selected-tags='vm.query.fields'></tag-complete>
```

Comment: Hate to be that guy, you're probably just doing this for fun, but just in case, have you seen: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete

Comment: If you add a log into `addToSelectedTags ` (console.log) you don't see anything? It should work this way

Comment: i have put a breakpoint inside the function and it does not trigger.  I have seen ngAutocomplete but want to make my own so that it does exactly what I need and no more, no less.

Comment: If you remove the `ng-click="focus()"` handler on the `article` element, does that help?

Comment: Nope, no difference after removing the ng-click='focus()'.

Comment: I have noticed that when the link function is run; the ng-repeat has not been placed on the DOM yet.  Relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-click should be firing. I tried inputting your code into a fiddle, and modified it a bit:
http://jsfiddle.net/vt52bauu/5/

You can try clicking the li-elements. I found a problem with this part of your code:

```
ng-click="addToSelectedTags($index)"
```

When you write something into the searchInput, it will filter your ng-repeat list. $index will therefore not match the indexes in your tagList and it might  try to add something that already exists in your selectedTags list. I changed it to input the tag directly:

```
ng-click="addToSelectedTags(tag)"
```

The other things I changed in the code was just to get it to run inside of jsFiddle.
Does this help your issue? The only other thing I can think of causing this, is something related to css.

Comment: While this wasn't the direct problem I was facing, it did however lead me to the answer so thanks very much! The problem was that I had the ng-blur setting the drop down to hidden which was happening fractions of a second before the click handler fired.  And thanks for solving this other bug in my code that I would have run into next.